# Attaching a csv/pdf file with sendmail functionality in python to run on linux box

Tags: python, linux, sendmail

My python script runs on linux server and here is the code that works to send email. But I need to attach a csv/pdf in the email and I couldn't find any straight answer. my email sending method is as shown below

```
def send_message(recipient, subject, body)
    process = subprocess.Popen(['mail', '-s', subject, recipient],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.communicate(body)
```

Note: I tried adding -A flag with filename to be attached, but somehow its not working
eg:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['mail', '-s', subject, '-A', attachment, recipient],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

While calling the function I pass the filename directly without path because csv file exists in the same path where script is running, it throws error

```
trigger_script.go:76: Account gw_ext_ecs_batch_218_seq_1.csv does not exist.
```

I think its taking it as account instead of attachment

Answer (score 0):

using -a instead of -A solved the issue